# Azure Active Directory - Add Users with multiple agencies/roles

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

In my current non-Azure AD, I am handling agents for a insurance company.  A given Agent could be a member of multiple agencies where the agent's roles could be different at each agency.  Something like this:

[image]

Based on the Azure Portal, the only approach that I can see (and I do not want to do it) is to make each Group/Role be a group and have the user be part of the the Group/Role group.  Something like this:

[image]

But this approach would cause me to create 4 or 5 times the groups that I truly need and seems messy to maintain.  Is there an approach that I am not seeing that would give me similar functionality in AAD that I currently have in my non-Azure AD?

Comment: The question is too generic and there is no `single`, neither `better` approach. You may also take a look at [Azure AD Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles). Having said that, the format of the question does not really fit the StackOverflow format (i.e.: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic )

Comment: Please kindly make your question more specific.

Comment: I guess that is part of my problem.  I do not know how to make it more specific as this work load was dumped on me and I do not have any experience doing this type of stuff.  I understand what needs to be done (create user/group roles so a given user can have different roles depending on which group it is looking at) but I do not understand how to accomplish something like this with AAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not assign AAD roles to a group, you need to assign the roles to the specific user.

Refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/12938997-azuread-role-delegation-to-groups) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  It is a bummer that Microsoft hasn't responded to that feedback after so many months.